# Twilio screen shot web

Tags: twilio, screenshot, twilio-api

I am implementing Twilio Video calling API and according to my use-case, I need to take screenshot while the call is going. … I tried the html2canvas library but it's showing black img.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you attempting to take a screenshot? Please provide the relevant code to show what you've tried.

Comment: Hey, would love to help too, can you share any code you have as well as whether you are receiving any errors in the browser dev tools.